# "Io faccio" or "Faccio io"?

Tags: word-order

I heard both versions of this sentence and I wonder which one is the correct one.
In the Google translator it says "Io faccio", but in the real world I heard multiple times "Faccio io".

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both are short sentences consisting of two words: *Io* is “I”, the first-person pronoun; *faccio* is the first person of the present tense of the verb *fare*, “to do”.

This said, both are possible Italian sentences, with different meanings. *Io faccio* simply, plainly means “I do” and lacks an object. The person you are speaking to would likely ask you something like *Fai che cosa?* (“You do what?”).

*Faccio io* is used only in specific contexts, since it stresses the *io* part, almost as in: “Step aside and let me do it”.

Comment: Thank you a lot, completely understood

Comment: @Bob Maybe it's obvious, but it's worth also noting that "Io faccio", while it can be translated with "I do", does not always have the same meaning of "I do" because "fare" does not have the same auxiliary use in Italian that it has in English. (E.g. you can't translate "Do you want to go shopping? I do!" with "Vuoi andare a far compere? Lo faccio!", that doesn't make sense, but you can translate e.g. "I do a lot of things" with "(Io) faccio molte cose"). Another possible translation is "I make".

Comment: @user2723984 well, my scenario is that we discuss tasks in our meetings and normally I want to say I do it/ I will do it, so after this answer, I use "faccio io" and I hope it is the correct approach.

Comment: @Bob: In this case it sounds a tad too brusque. It might be better to say _Ci penso io_, _Me ne occupo io_ or even _Lo faccio io_, while just _Faccio io_, without even an object, sounds a bit like you wanted to silence the person you are talking to.